# Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 and 5 on iPhone 5s iOS 8.1.2 and Simulator 8.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, xcode6

I receive on a iPhone 5s with iOS v8.1.2 the following messages in the Xcode console:

- Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 3876877096_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
- Can't find keyplane that supports type 5 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-PhonePad; using 2870935746_Portrait_iPhone-Complex-Pad_Default

Does someone knows what's going wrong? The keyboards are shown as expected.
Same is valid for the iOS Simulator v8.1.I just like to get rid of these warnings.

Thanks

Comment: I already got feedback in the Apple developer forum. It's a known issue at Apple. But it seems they are currently not working actively on it. The Apple member recommended just to ignore the console output.

Comment: Thanks. Ping me whenever you got response from Apple about bug resolved. (@Morpheus78)

Comment: @Morpheus78 do you have the link from the issue on apple forum?

Comment: Have a look to this: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1086514#1086514

Comment: @Morpheus78 hi, I got this issue also on my iPhone 6s plus. Seems this link can't be shown. What does it say? Thanks!

Comment: @S1U They said: `It's a known issue, but as far as I know, it's just benign logging.  Are you experiencing any functionality problems?  If so, please file a radar.`

Answer (score 12):

This is a known issue for several devices and Apple doesn't seem to want to fix it, as you said the keyboard you've requested still shows up and works properly. Filing a radar with apple is frequently the only thing you can do, then start hoping!

http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: I reported it.  If I get an answer I'll post it back here.

Comment: it seems that nothing will make Apple fix this....     We need to start a petition in change.org

Comment: same here. 2022 and still not fixed

Answer (score 0):

if it will help some one , i have this problem on cordova capacitor also , it was very strange for me until i remeber i put on css

```
*{
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE10+/Edge */
  user-select: none;
  /* Standard */
}
```

yes it make keyboard have no access to fields also
if you face same issue exactly :
change * to div,span,img etc....