# Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad

Tags: ios, xcode, uikeyboard

I recently upgraded to Xcode 7 and today I noticed this warning in the log when I tapped a text field and the keyboard popped up:

> Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 563160167_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

I have a `UITextField` that I set up in Interface Builder and configured it (also in IB) to display a number pad keyboard. I also noticed that for a normal type of keyboard this message does not appear.

I searched for a solution but none of what I found worked so far.

The simulator settings under `Simulator -> Hardware -> Keyboard` are:

Checked for `Uses same layout as OS X`
Unchecked for the other two.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 and 5 on iPhone 5s iOS 8.1.2 and Simulator 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636943/cant-find-keyplane-that-supports-type-4-and-5-on-iphone-5s-ios-8-1-2-and-simula)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your iOS App can't find a Numeric Keypad attached to your OS X. So you just need to Uncheck connect Hardware Keyboard option in your Simulator, in the following path just for **testing purpose:**

> `Simulator` -> `Hardware` -> `Keyboard` -> `Connect Hardware Keyboard`

This will resolve the above issue.

I think you should see the [following link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19639) too. It says it's a bug in the XCode at the end of that Forum post thread!

**Hint:**
And also I think this is a point where you need to give a Soft-keyboard `Close` button just above the Number Keypad.

Comment: I noticed this error also while runing on the iPod touch while connencted to my laptop.

Comment: @AlexCraciun I think that's totally another problem, but the above works for the iOS Simulator as I understood.

Comment: @AlexCraciun I updated my answer with giving another link to Apple Forum. Please follow it. Cheers!

Comment: I fixed this issue by selecting erase all content and settings in hardware of simulator.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're running the app on OS X and there is no numeric keypad attached to OS X. The solution is this:

[image]

Comment: I get the same error when I run the app on my iPod touch while connected to Xcode. Why?

Comment: I'm running directly on my device and same error as well, has nothing to do with simulator.

Comment: I have the same Error running on iPhone 7, someone has solved it?

Comment: same error iPhone 6 Xcode 9... will it be in production too?